# This field name is not known. Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

Error in File BFCSTMSTM01 11696_9116_{FF6EA1CE-2497-45FF-81AE-E8828FB271AE}.rpt:
Error in formula  Fline_Balance:
'{#RTotal_Debit}+{#RTotal_Credit}+{#RTotal_VAT}+{#RTotal_CrdVAT}-{BF_RPT91_PKG_BFCSTMSTM01_RPT.VAT_AMOUNT}-{BF_RPT91_PKG_BFCSTMSTM01_RPT.VAT_CRD_AMOUNT}
'
This field name is not known.
Details: errorKind

Comment: Please need help the above issues

Comment: Issues Resolved by correcting the object value

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.